# How to fill an entire area in the body?

Tags: css, colors

Let me explain: I want to fill an entire area in the body e.g.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Fill an entire area</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="header">
         This area is red.
      </div>
      <div id="middle">
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

The Div-tag "header" should be red colored, but if I write

```
#header {
   position: relative;
   background-color: red;
}
```

The header will be red, but there are little white spaces around it.

[image]

Instead of it, I want it without white spaces. Is there a way to do this in CSS without using Bootstrap?

[image]

Sorry, if there was a similar question. I didn't know how to explain my problem.

Comment: Did you try `body{margin:0;padding:0}` ?

Comment: Is that your entire HTML file? In that case, I would ***strongly*** advise using a doctype declaration. It will prevent all kinds of ioncompatibility headaches.

Comment: did you inspect your code element in the browser yet?

Comment: @Obink If the OP doesn't know about margins, I doubt inspecting the body or the div would be of much use.

Comment: @MrLister what is OP stands for? outplayed?

Comment: @Obink Original Poster (or sometimes, Original Post, i.e. the question)

Comment: @MrLister ooo i got it now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because of default `margin` of body or `margin` of your `#header`, use this:

```
body, #header {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `margin:0;padding:0` to body should solve the problem you are facing here.